# SF required multi-factor authentications starting February 2022 OAuth JWT Bearer Token flow

Tags: jwt, multi-factor-authentication

I am using JWT flow described bellow
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5
and SF required multi-factor authentications starting February 2022
question :
Will new requirement break JWT flow?
do I need to change anything regarding settings of the app and JWT auth?
we are leveraging usernames of users

Answer (score 2):

No. API-based flows won't require MFA. This is covered in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1).

> | Login Type / Authentication Method | MFA Required? | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | API / Integration Logins | No | To set up API connections and integrations, admins must log in with MFA. |

API-based logins and Automation Testing Users won't require MFA, nor external users. There's actually a number of exceptions that's worth reading about in the documentation.

Comment: The strange this is: as soon as I set Session Security Level of the profile (of the user that requests the token) to High Assurance, the interface stops working. "invalid session id". Clearing the Session Security Level of the profile makes the interface work again immediately. For me this conflicts with "MFA Required? No"

Comment: @SanderdeJong What interface are you using? Tell me more about this.

Comment: I have created a new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362065/how-is-salesforce-going-to-enforce-mfa-in-the-upcoming-release

Answer (score 0):

From a POC i did JWT with MFA enable using Profile is not possible, Salesforce provide an AccessToken but you cannot use it in API call.
When MFA enable using Permission set you Can Use the AccessToken.